# using an object passed as a function argument (function is defined inside another class)

Tags: python, function, object, arguments

I am trying to access an object which was passed to my function (defined inside my class).

- Essentially  I am  invoking  a  function  `publish_alert`  defined  inside  class  `AlertPublishInterface`.
- caller  passes  into  `publish_alert`  an  instance  of  a  class  called  `AlertVO`
- once  I  receive  this  passed  argument  instance  via  `publish_alert`,  I am  simply  trying  to  access  the  data  members  of  the  passed  argument  instance  inside  class  `AlertPublishInterface` (in  which  called  function  `publish_alert`  is  defined.
- I  get  `AttributeError`  in  step 2,  i.e.,  when  accessing  members  of  the  passed  argument  instance  as:

  AttributeError: AlertPublishInterface instance has no attribute 'alert_name'

Here  is  code  snippet:

AlertPublishInterface  file:

```
import datetime
import logging.config           

import django_model_importer    

logging.config.fileConfig('logging.conf')
logger = logging.getLogger('alert_publish_interface')


from  alert.models  import  AlertRule  #Database  table  objects  defined  in  the  model  file         
from  alert.models  import  AlertType  #Database  table  objects  defined  in  the  model  file  

import  AlertVO  #This  is instance  whose  members  am  trying  to  simple  access  below...!     


class  AlertPublishInterface:     

    def  publish_alert(o_alert_vo,  dummy_remove):   
        print o_alert_vo.alert_name   #-----1----#   
        alerttype_id = AlertType.objects.filter(o_alert_vo.alert_name,
                o_alert_vo.alert_category,  active_exact=1)    #-----2----#
        return
```

AlertVO  is  defined  as:

```
class  AlertVO:   

    def  __init__(self, alert_name, alert_category, notes,
            monitor_item_id,  monitor_item_type,  payload):  
        self.alert_name =  alert_name       
        self.alert_category =  alert_category   
        self.notes  =  notes    
        self.monitor_item_id  =  monitor_item_id    
        self.monitor_item_type  =  monitor_item_type     
        self.payload  =  payload
```

calling  code  snippet (which  invokes  `AlertPublishInterface`'s  `publish_alert`  function):

```
from  AlertVO  import  AlertVO      

from  AlertPublishInterface  import  AlertPublishInterface;  

o_alert_vo  =  AlertVO(alert_name='BATCH_SLA', alert_category='B',
        notes="some  notes",  monitor_item_id=2,  monitor_item_type='B',
        payload='actual=2,  expected=1')       

print  o_alert_vo.alert_name     
print  o_alert_vo.alert_category    
print  o_alert_vo.notes   
print  o_alert_vo.payload  

alert_publish_i  =  AlertPublishInterface()     
alert_publish_i.publish_alert(o_alert_vo)
```

However  it  fails  at  lines  marked  #-----1----#  and  #-----2---#  above  with  type  error,  seems  like  it's  associating  `AlertVO`  object (the  `o_alert_vo`  instance)  with  `AlertPublishInterface`  class:

complete  block  of  screen  output  at  run:

```
python  test_publisher.py 
In  test_publisher
BATCH_SLA
B
some  notes
actual=2,  expected=1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_publisher.py", line 17, in 
    alert_publish_i.publish_alert(o_alert_vo.alert_name)        
  File "/home/achmon/data_process/AlertPublishInterface.py", line 26, in publish_alert
    print  o_alert_vo.alert_name      
AttributeError: AlertPublishInterface instance has no attribute 'alert_name'
```

Can't  rid  of  above  error  after  a  lot  of  searching  around...can  someone  please  help...?

Thanks...!(kinda  urgent  too...!)

Comment: Are AlertVO  and AlertPublishInterface  file names as well as class names? You should follow PEP8 guidlines. file names should be all lower case. Class names are CamelCase, as you have done.

Answer (score 2):

The reason you are getting this error is because the first argument is the class itself. Normally, this is called self.

I can also identify this as being django (in which case, you should also be inheriting, if not from some other django class, then from object to make it a new style class)

Anyway, just add self as your first argument in publish_ alert and it will probably stop throwing that error.

Comment: @user1272435 you should accept an answer on stack if something worked for you. it's good edicate (and it improves your accept score)

Answer (score 1):

`def  publish_alert(o_alert_vo,  dummy_remove):` should be `def  publish_alert(self, o_alert_vo,  dummy_remove):`